# Plotting a jqPlot in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, jqplot

Hi and thanks for all your answers.

My problem is that I want to use the jqPlot library in my webapp which Im developing using the framework Symfony2.

Here goes my view:

```
    <head>
 {% javascripts '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/*'  %} 



<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}


</head>

<body>
<h1>test</h1>



 <div id="chart1" style="height:200px; width:600px;"></div>
  {% javascripts '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/*'  %} 
  <script type="text/javascript" class="code">
$(document).ready(function(){
    goog = [["6/22/2009",425.32], ["6/8/2009",424.84], ["5/26/2009",417.23], ["5/11/2009",390], 
    ["4/27/2009",393.69], ["4/13/2009",392.24], ["3/30/2009",369.78], ["3/16/2009",330.16], ["3/2/2009",308.57], 
    ["2/17/2009",346.45], ["2/2/2009",371.28], ["1/20/2009",324.7], ["1/5/2009",315.07], ["12/22/2008",300.36], 
    ["12/8/2008",315.76], ["11/24/2008",292.96], ["11/10/2008",310.02], ["10/27/2008",359.36], ["10/13/2008",372.54],
    ["9/29/2008",386.91], ["9/15/2008",449.15], ["9/2/2008",444.25], ["8/25/2008",463.29],  ["8/11/2008",510.15], 
    ["7/28/2008",467.86], ["7/14/2008",481.32], ["6/30/2008",537], ["6/16/2008",546.43], ["6/2/2008",567], 
    ["5/19/2008",544.62], ["5/5/2008",573.2], ["4/21/2008",544.06], ["4/7/2008",457.45], ["3/24/2008",438.08], 
    ["3/10/2008",437.92], ["2/25/2008",471.18], ["2/11/2008",529.64], ["1/28/2008",515.9], ["1/14/2008",600.25], 
    ["12/31/2007",657], ["12/17/2007",696.69], ["12/3/2007",714.87], ["11/19/2007",676.7], ["11/5/2007",663.97], 
    ["10/22/2007",674.6], ["10/8/2007",637.39], ["9/24/2007",567.27], ["9/10/2007",528.75], ["8/27/2007",515.25]];

    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [goog], { 
        title: 'Google, Inc.', 
        series: [{ 
            label: 'Google, Inc.', 
            neighborThreshold: -1 
        }], 
        axes: { 
            xaxis: { 
                renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                  angle: -30
                } 
            }, 
            yaxis: {  
                renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
                tickOptions:{ prefix: '$' } 
            } 
        }, 
        cursor:{
            show: true, 
            zoom: true
        } 
    });
});
</script>



  {% endjavascripts %}

</body>
```

the problem is that when I render my view the graphic is not plotted although the graph is there when I check it on "view source code".

UPDATE: I just check the code several times and I think it is no problem of the code. Could it be a symfony problem? An Internet navigator config problem (I'm using Chrome)

UPDATE2: In the javascript console of Google Chrome i have these error messages "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined test:21
(anonymous function)"

UPDATE3: This is the same code I used in a .html file I've created and it works so I think that the problem is related to the Symfony2 framework. I guess now this is a question that any person who has worked with symfony and included javascript code can easyly answer

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your page?

Comment: Yeah, jQuery is incluyed in the package of the jqPlot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was the way I include the .js files. Instead of :

```
{% javascripts '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/*'  %} 



<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Diego\Desktop\Practicas\predit\src\Goodday\PreditBundle\Resources\public\js\plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

The CORRECT way to do it is :

```
{% javascripts '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
               '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js'
               '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js'
               '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js' 
               '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/plugins/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.min.js'
               '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js' 
               '@PreditBundle/Resources/public/js/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```